# Send String (Parsed as integer) as Object to REST api in Flutter

Tags: flutter, rest

I am trying to send this as a Request to an endpoint. Normally it sends the amount object as an integer. Now i want to parse the data from a string and send it but if i do it like this, It does not send rather it gives me this as error

```
I/flutter (26554): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (26554): <html>
I/flutter (26554): ^
```

The code is Looking thus :

```
final body ={
"account_bank":bankName,
"account_number":accountNum,
"amount":int.parse(amount),
"narration":narration,
"currency":currency,
"meta":{
"first_name":firstName,
"last_name":lastName,
"email":email,
"recipient_address":address,
"mobile_number":mobileNumber,   
},
"beneficiary_name":beneficiaryName,
}
```

I am using Flutter to send this Payload to the server. How do I go about this?

**Edits**

Please see the required information

```
void southAfricaTransfer({
    required String amount,
    required String narration,
    required String currency,
    required String bankName,
    required String accountNum,
    required String email,
    required String firstName,
    required String lastName,
    required String address,
    required String mobileNum,
    required String beneficiaryName,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();

    String url = AppUrl.saTransfer;
    // SharedPreferences pref = await _pref;
    // String tokenUser = pref.getString('token') ?? '';

    final body = {
      "account_bank": bankName,
      "account_number": accountNum,
      "amount": int.parse(amount),
      "narration": narration,
      "currency": currency,
      "meta": {
        "first_name": firstName,
        "last_name": lastName,
        "email": email,
        "recipient_address": address,
        "mobile_number": mobileNum,
      },
      "beneficiary_name": beneficiaryName,
    };

    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer FLWSECK_TEST-153740d351951b5f6d5ae8b903e0c467-X'
    };

    //making http request
    http.Response req = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers: headers, body: json.encode(body));
    print(json.encode(body));
    try {
      if (req.statusCode == 200 || req.statusCode == 201) {
        final res = json.decode(req.body);
        print(res);
        _isLoading = false;
        _reqMessage = "Transfer Successful";

        pushNotification(
            'Money Transfer Complete', 'Successfully sent $amount');
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        final res = json.decode(req.body);
        print(res);
        _isLoading = false;
        _reqMessage = 'Unable to process';
        notifyListeners();
      }
    } on SocketException catch (_) {
      _isLoading = false;
      print(_);
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can you give more context around where you instantiate the variables listed in "body" as well as how you are using the object?

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope Please see Edits

Comment: What's the raw vaule of amount?

Comment: @AlejandroCumpa, pls explain what u mean by raw value?

Comment: The error suggest that the value of "amount" has a "<html>" marker inside it, I think if you're seeing it maybe it's like a  "<html> 3440</html>" so it looks like it's only 3440, but the raw value has the markers.

Comment: ^ Exactly what Alejandro is saying. What are the values for this object you are passing through. One of those values is most likely not correct and has that html element that is causing your error.